# Python Py2D - Polygon convex decomposition (Polygon.convex_decompose()) adds extra area instead of decomposing a concave face into convex faves

Tags: python, polygon, python-3.9, convex-polygon, concave

I am trying to decompose some concave faces into convex faces that cover the same area as the original concave face. I found a package online that should be able to do this (http://sseemayer.github.io/Py2D/documentation/features/convex_decompose.html) however I do no get it to work.

**I have tried it with the following lines of code:**
from py2d.Math import Polygon, Vector

P = Polygon [(2.00, 3.00), (3.00, 3.00), (3.00, 2.00), (4.00, 2.00), (4.00, 4.00), (2.00, 4.00), (2.00, 3.00)]
P = Polygon.convex_decompose(P)

**P than becomes:**
[Polygon [(3.00, 2.00), (3.00, 3.00), (2.00, 3.00)], Polygon [(2.00, 3.00), (2.00, 4.00), (4.00, 4.00), (4.00, 2.00), (3.00, 2.00), (2.00, 3.00)]]

Which is the area of the original face plus an extra triangle. I would have expected two (or more) convex polygons that cover the same area as the original polygon (see images).

**The original polygon**

[image: The original polygon]**The area of the result polygon**
[image: The combined area of the 'decomposed' polygons]
[image: Expected polygons]

Thanks for taking a look! I would love to hear your solutions.

Comment: Have you tried this one https://pypi.org/project/poly_decomp/

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work! The problem was that I defined a closed polygon:

```
P = Polygon [(2.00, 3.00), (3.00, 3.00), (3.00, 2.00), (4.00, 2.00), (4.00, 4.00), (2.00, 4.00), (2.00, 3.00)]
```

However `Py2D` assumes that the last given point connects with the first point. Thus by changing the code to:

```
P = Polygon [(2.00, 3.00), (3.00, 3.00), (3.00, 2.00), (4.00, 2.00), (4.00, 4.00), (2.00, 4.00)] 

P = Polygon.convex_decompose(P)
```

I got the expected result.